# Excel VBA doesn't recognize manually opened .xlam add-in

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I have an excel add-in that can't be found in `Application.AddIns`. I'm manually opening the add-in by going to File -> Open -> browse to `addin.xlam`. Do add-ins need to be programmatically added in order to show up in `Application.AddIns`?

EDIT

@Fadi

I do not see my addin in either of these print functions. In the first one, it just prints the name of my current workbook and that is all. The second one successfully prints out my other 10 add-ins that have been programmatically added, but not the one that was manually added.

```
Sub MsgWorkbooks()

    Dim s As String
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        s = s + app.Name
    Next wb
    MsgBox s

End Sub

Sub MsgAddIns()

    Dim s As String
    For Each app In Application.AddIns
        s = s + app.Name
    Next app
    MsgBox s

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have time to test, but am sure the answer is yes. I think `Application.Addins` represents the collection of addins in the addins dialog. In fact, that's pretty much word-for-word how MSDN defines it.

Comment: _that was manually added_ are you mean you add it [like this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-add-ins-0af570c4-5cf3-4fa9-9b88-403625a0b460#bmexceladdin). if so it should be a part of `AddIns` collection and your second sub should show it's name.

Comment: No I mean File >> Open >> (Browse and double click your addin)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to install it:

```
Sub InstallAddIn()
    Dim AI As Excel.AddIn
    Set AI = Application.AddIns.Add(Filename:="d:\addin.xlam") 'change the addin fullname 
    AI.Installed = True
End Sub
```

more information [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/installinganxla.aspx)

As Doug Glancy comment we can check whether the addin is available like any normal workbook. so we can use this function:

```
Function IsAddinLoaded(adName As String) As Boolean

  Dim addinWB As Workbook

  On Error Resume Next
   Set addinWB = Workbooks(adName)
   If Err = 0 Then IsAddinLoaded = True
  On Error GoTo 0      

End Function
```

To test:

```
Sub Test()

   if IsAddinLoaded("addin.xlam") = true Then ' change the name of addin
    msgbox "Addin is loaded"
   Else
    msgbox "Addin not loaded"
   End if

End Sub
```

Comment: That's just the thing. I want a macro that runs a function from the addin, but I want to make sure the addin is installed first. So all I need is an if statement that checks whether the addin is available. I want this to work whether the addin has been manually opened, or programmatically installed.

Comment: You can just check if it's open. An open addin is part of the `Workbooks` collection, just like any other workbook, whether it's installed or opened manually.